# windows32 pyinstaller matplotlib PySide init required argument

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

i'm trying to compile python application using pyinstaller. This application import Pyside and Matplotlib, on a windows32
Note that without pyinstaller the application works.

I have reduce the application to point the problem.

Here my class using matplotlib :

```
import matplotlib as plt
plt.use('Qt4Agg')
plt.rcParams['backend.qt4'] = 'PySide'
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import PySide.QtGui as QtGui
import PySide


class MatplotlibWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MatplotlibWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.figure = Figure(facecolor='white')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(self.figure)

def main():
    import sys
    app = PySide.QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MatplotlibWidget(PySide.QtGui.QWidget())
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I compiling using this spec file :

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['uis/consoresidentielWindow.py'],
             pathex=['./src/', './uis/', 'C:\\Users\\jcare\\Desktop\\TestInstall'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('./assets/datas/*', 'assets/datas'),('./assets/icons/*', 'assets/icons'),('./assets/video/*', 'assets/video')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='consoresidentielWindow',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='consoresidentielWindow')
```

this throw me this traceback :

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
    File "matplotWidget.py", line 110, in <module>
    File "matplotWidget.py", line 105, in main
    File "matplotWidget.py", line 25, in __init__
    File "site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt4agg.py.py", line 76, in __init__
    File "site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt4.py.py", line 66, in __init__
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'figure'
Failed to execute script matplotWidget
```

I dond't unterstand why this crash. when i print PySide.QtGui.**version**, that good : 4.8.7
Probably a hook problem ? but i do not find the good library to hook.
If somoene have an idea.
Thanks

Few Research : 
I identify the problem :

```
plt.use('Qt4Agg')
plt.rcPArams['backend.qt4'] = 'PySide'
```

Do not work with pyinstaller. I have no idea how fix it

Few Search later :

The problem is not plt.use('Qt4Agg') and plt.rcPArams['backend.qt4'] = 'PySide'

When i print they values, they are fine. That point that again a problem of includes or something like that.